# Running into an invalid quorum set error when running stellar-core

Tags: stellar-core

I installed `stellar-core` and all the tests passed. I used `docs/stellar-core_example.cfg` and tried to run stellar like so

```
stellar-core -D stellar-example.cfg
```

but I'm getting an error

```
2018-03-16T17:08:12.139 GBA2J [default INFO] Starting stellar-core v9.2.0rc5-12-ga340312c
2018-03-16T17:08:12.139 GBA2J [default INFO] Config from stellar-example.cfg
2018-03-16T17:08:12.140 GBA2J [Database INFO] Connecting to: postgresql://dbname=stellar user=tamasnagy
2018-03-16T17:08:12.153 GBA2J [SCP INFO] LocalNode::LocalNode@GBA2J qSet: 99cf51
2018-03-16T17:08:12.154 GBA2J [default INFO] Listening on 127.0.0.1:11626 for HTTP requests
2018-03-16T17:08:12.156 GBA2J [History INFO] Archive 'local' has 'put' and 'get' commands, will be read and written
2018-03-16T17:08:12.157 GBA2J [default INFO] ll?level=info&partition=Herder -> {
   "Herder" : "Info"
}

2018-03-16T17:08:12.159 GBA2J [default FATAL] Got an exception: Invalid QUORUM_SET: duplicate entry or bad threshold (should be between 51 and 100) [main.cpp:647]
2018-03-16T17:08:12.159 GBA2J [default INFO] Application destructing
2018-03-16T17:08:12.160 GBA2J [default INFO] Application destroyed
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your quorum set. Would you mind sharing this (if you are worried about privacy, you can swap out the node_keys and/or names)?

Comment: I'm just using the default quorum set from `docs/stellar-core_example.cfg` on the latest stellar-core master

Comment: I don't believe this quorum set has real validator account id's -- it primarily is used to show an example quorum set structure. Checkout dashboard.stellar.org for a list of validators to choose for your quorum set.

Answer (score 1):

I took the time to setup stellar-core and was able to reproduce your error:

```
2018-03-19T09:19:59.769 GBA2J [default INFO] Starting stellar-core v9.2.0rc6
2018-03-19T09:19:59.769 GBA2J [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
2018-03-19T09:19:59.769 GBA2J [Database INFO] Connecting to: postgresql://dbname=core user=rob password=********
2018-03-19T09:19:59.772 GBA2J [SCP INFO] LocalNode::LocalNode@GBA2J qSet: e666b6
2018-03-19T09:19:59.772 GBA2J [default INFO] Listening on 127.0.0.1:11626 for HTTP requests
2018-03-19T09:19:59.774 GBA2J [History INFO] Archive 'local' has 'put' and 'get' commands, will be read and written
2018-03-19T09:19:59.776 GBA2J [default INFO] ll?level=info&partition=Herder -> {
   "Herder" : "Info"
}

2018-03-19T09:19:59.777 GBA2J [default FATAL] Got an exception: Invalid QUORUM_SET: duplicate entry or bad threshold (should be between 51 and 100) [main.cpp:647]
2018-03-19T09:19:59.777 GBA2J [default INFO] Application destructing
2018-03-19T09:19:59.777 GBA2J [default INFO] Application destroyed
```

In doing so, I noticed the following in the (recently???) updated admin.md:

> The example config is not a real configuration and is the most
>   important one: it documents all possible configuration elements as
>   well as default values.

So I recommend instead using a config such [as this](https://github.com/stellar/docs/blob/master/other/stellar-core-validator-example.cfg) (and then of course selecting your own quorum set!).